# Eclipse internal error while creating project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have recently installed CDT module in Eclipse and now I have problem with creating a project. 
And here is the problem:

Internal Error:  org/eclipse/cdt/core/language/settings/providers/ScannerDiscoveryLegacySupport

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "internal error" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)