# Google People API. OthersContact endpoint internal error

Tags: google-apis-explorer

We are having the following error when using Google People API for OtherContacts.

error:

{
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal error encountered.",
"status": "INTERNAL"
}
}

How to reproduce:
[Google Endpoint for test purpose](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A1000%2C%22readMask%22%3A%22names%22%7D)

There is a google "Support" link that asks to create a question in stackoverflow, so here you are.

Is this "Internal Error" something that google needs to fix or am I doing something wrong?

[Google API Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5rZ7.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "internal error" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: "that asks to create a question in stackoverflow": I doubt that. This is not user support for Google.