# Couldn't inline method call 'remember'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Would you please advise what is wrong with the code: I got JVM error while building:

Kotlin version = 1.5.21

Compose version = 1.0.1

> Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call 'remember' into
> @androidx.compose.runtime.Composable public fun TelephoneEditText(`$composer`: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer?, `$changed`: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit defined in com.example.scrapper.ui
>
> Cause: Not generated
> File is unknown
> The root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen$Companion.getCompiledMethodNodeInner(InlineCodegen.kt:578)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.throwCompilationException(InlineCodegen.kt:101)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:141)

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TextEditOnScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        TelephoneEditText()
    }
}

@Composable
fun TelephoneEditText() {
    val textValue = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val primaryColor = colorResource(id = R.color.design_default_color_primary)

    OutlinedTextField(
        label = { Text(text = stringResource(id =
        R.string.phoneNumber)) },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = primaryColor,
            focusedLabelColor = primaryColor,
            cursorColor = primaryColor
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        value = textValue.value,
        onValueChange = {textValue.value = it},
    )
}
```

**RESOLVED**

Replaced:

```
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev14'
```

with

```
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57357557/545127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compose code is totally fine.

The issue is probably somewhere in your dependencies or in gradle setup

Try creating a new compose project to see if it reproduces.

If it works fine, compare gradle setup to find out what's different

If it doesn't work, consider reporting it to [compose issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) with AS logs and code of your sample project

Comment: Your're right, the problem caused by incorrect dependencies: replaced    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev14' with implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version" and build was successfull