# PHP_FPM error - "oops, unknown child (538) exited with code 0"

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, yii, fpm

I am trying to start up my **PHP YII1** framework based application in docker containers. However, PHP_FPM is not properly getting started.

After running: `exec /usr/sbin/php-fpm -F -c /etc/php.ini --fpm-config /etc/php-fpm.conf`     within a shell script, the application is supposed to start up. However, I m getting an internal error.

When checking the docker logs, below is the result:

> [18-Aug-2021 18:44:46] NOTICE: Terminating ...
> [18-Aug-2021 18:44:46] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
> [18-Aug-2021 18:44:47] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
> [18-Aug-2021 18:44:48] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
> [18-Aug-2021 18:44:48] NOTICE: systemd monitor disabled
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (538) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (539) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (540) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (544) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (545) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (546) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (541) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (542) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (543) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (556) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (557) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (558) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (559) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (560) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (561) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (562) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (563) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (564) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (565) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (566) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (567) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (547) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (548) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (549) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (550) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (551) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (552) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (553) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (554) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (555) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (568) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (569) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (570) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (571) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (572) exited with code 1. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:01:44] ALERT: oops, unknown child (573) exited with code 0. Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
> [18-Aug-2021 19:04:05] NOTICE: Terminating ...
> [18-Aug-2021 19:04:05] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
> [18-Aug-2021 19:04:06] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
> [18-Aug-2021 19:04:06] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
> [18-Aug-2021 19:04:06] NOTICE: systemd monitor disabled

Does anyone know what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: this? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73342

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "internal error" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm seeing this with the php:7.4-fpm docker image running a Laravel 8 application and Kubernetes 1.20.9.  The exact same docker image deploys just fine in Kubernetes 1.19.13, and we have half a dozen other php:7.4-fpm images running Laravel 6.4 applications that don't have the same problem.  Evidently, it is some interaction between Laravel 8 and Kubernetes 1.20.9.  At a loss for how to debug.